# AMD & MacOS (2019)

Tags: osx

I thought I was fully up to speed on Blender's hardware requirements when building my latest machine,

- https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/
- https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/

... but it appears I needed to read the fine print a little more closely. Are AMD and MacOS now a non-starter with Blender (given the OpenCL issue with Apple)? 2.79 & 2.80 seem to crash completely with my Vega VII in MacOS, but both work absolutely fine in a VM running *Nix **on the same MacOS host and GPU**! Interesting.

Am I missing something? Is this an issue with Blender and the Vega VII? Or is there something missing MacOS-side that I would just need to update?

Comment: The removed support for OpenCL only means that GPU rendering isn't possible. The application should still run on supported systems and allow CPU rendering. Make sure that your graphics driver is updated. If that doesn't solve it, you should run Blender from console using the `--debug` flag to see why it crashes.

Comment: Many thanks, rjg! That makes some sense and was my gut feeling about it.

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess that AMD's ProRender can also do an end-run around the GPU-rendering issue you mention, rjg. Will re-post when I get some results. Thanks again!

Comment: ProRender supports Metal, so it will run on the GPU when using macOS.

Comment: Yep, exactly.

And... sure enough, it was an OS upgrade issue. Able to get everything running tickedy-boo. Thanks muchly, rjg.

Comment: You're welcome :) Glad I could help.

Comment: @Zlyxian follow also this topic: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/is-there-interest-in-supporting-a-metal-version-of-cycles-for-macos/ There seems to be some hope for Cycles and EEVEE when Blender will switch to Vulkan which then will allow to use MoltenVK in MacOS. Probalby. Maybe. It's classified ;)

Comment: I familiar with this discussion, too. The most blasé response I'd heard was, "Yeah, if it ever comes down to it, someone'll go MoltenVK. Didn't think it was classified, though... :)  Thanks, @cgslav.